# Сумма строки в двумерном массиве

Tags: c++

Всем доброго времени суток! Кто может подсказать мою ошибку в задаче.

**Дан двумерный массив целых чисел A, состоящий из n строк и m столбцов. Требуется найти и вывести сумму элементов каждой из строк массива A.** ([задача отсюда](https://statement.bacs.cs.istu.ru/statement/get/CjRiYWNzL3Byb2JsZW0vc2Nob29sXzdfMTJfMy9zdGF0ZW1lbnQvdmVyc2lvbnMvQy9odG1sEgYKBPeDSvQ/bacs/SGtQM1hdKOJ-Vs2AZkdF4KmeuJmJscsU6CbyXomhwHU0GnCk8WVrIPtFfHjAWRqU2MZQo0Q4fCTtSnZ1a9X0Fao85xbuV1BQYsARJLdjPXymRSfI27z0g_0-Axzl4qlGrb1fzw8dKe1SjLwrzfC63SkakKtZ4EKr2jwRjTsKD7DVtjxN7jqI4durti8ey01hYDP4NnEi5-tg3NkNvwXsmOM2tD5GfDxt8aMVy_yAnpm09vgN2K5jFi4xHZrM2kmx1PExG6SjgDiQU6BsgI61NpH1QYu8M6BhwIFSGT7pyG9HTIOOn5pGCgnBSDsLLjWi5NCl8VckcBpHBWg64tspUg/problem.html))

Нужно использовать функцию. У меня есть идейки, но не могу реализовать.

Код:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int get_sum(int a[], int n){
    int sum = 0;
   
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        sum+=a[i];

    }
    return sum;

}

int main()
{
    int n, m;
    int a[n][m];
    cin>>n>>m;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<m; j++) 
    cin>>a[i][j];
    }
    for (int j=0; j<m; j++) 
    cout<<get_sum(a, n);
    
    
}
```

Comment: 1) Сперва нужно считать значения в переменные `n` и `m`, а потом объявлять массив: `cin>>n>>m; int a[n][m];`. Вообще, размер массива должен быть известен на этапе компиляции, но не которые компиляторы позволяют делать и так. 2) `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) cout << get_sum(a[i], m) << ' ';`